# Azure Website Automation using powershell cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-automation

I am looking for information on how to set the website general settings through powershell cmdlets. When I create a new Website through gallery and choose Apache Tomcat 7 it default selects the .net framework. I would like to set those off and use Java version .

Don't see any commands to set that default while creating a website.

Also, how can I set already available (in profile) SSL certificate and traffic manager end point to my new website using powershell cmdlets.

Thanks in Advance.

tnb

Answer (score 0):

The selection of the .Net Framework deosn't affect the behaviour of your Tomcat install.

Right now there isn't a PS1 Cmdlet that will let you select the Tomcat 7 when setting up a Website (or changing its configuration via Set-AzureWebsite).

There was an Azure Cross Platform CLI method to setup SSL certificates for websites (azure site cert) which has since been removed and there is no equivalent in the PS1 Cmdlets either.

You can add Traffic Manager Endpoints easily enough by utilising the [Add-AzureTafficManagerEndpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn690257.aspx) Cmdlet and pass in the azurewebsites.net address of your Website instance.